# specify order of variables in position dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I honestly don't know why this is being so hard.

I'm creating a simple scatter plot. The x axis is a continuous variable, and at every tick in x I need to plot four points with error bars. I'm using position dodge and everything works fine.

Each point has a different color, size and shape as governed by three further variables: color and shape are governed by factors, size by a continuous variable.

By default, the four points reflect the order of the levels in the color variable (red always left, then green, then blue) but I would like them to reflect the order of the size variable (the continuous one), smallest left and largest right. How do I specify that size should be prioritised when ordering points in position dodge? I tried using reverse ordering but then the points are ordered first according to the shape legend.

I could change the mapping between variable and aesthetics (all variables are fundamentally continuous and could be used with size) but I think it'd be useful to know how to specify the order in which multiple variables should be considered when dodging points.

[image: this is the plot I obtain]

Comment: welcome to SO. Would you kindly help us help you and provide a sample data set to play with. Also, it would help us understand where youre stuck when you would show us how you got to this plot so far (i.e. please post your code). It's always much easier to take a solution from an already more or less working plot. It takes a bit of time to make reproducible examples, and it is courtesy to us to provide this

Comment: Also please clarify if the dodge would be constant or if a different dodge should be allowed for each x - meaning if the order within the size variable can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear unfortunately. You don't show "a simple scatter plot". You are showing some statistics (mean with error band??) for specific x values - although this is seemingly continuous, this looks as if you have categorised it beforehand - resulting in some summary statistics which you are plotting.

Also, it is not easy (impossible) to fully help you without knowing what you have done until now to come to where you are.

I have tried to reproduce a similar looking plot with `mtcars`.
Dodging is only possible by one group (but one group can contain more than one variable). To specify how to group, add `group = ...` to your aesthetics.

Like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(filter(mtcars, carb %in% 1:4)) +
  geom_point(aes(carb, mpg, size= gear, group = gear, shape = as.character(vs), color = as.factor(cyl)), 
             position = position_dodge(width = .5))
```

[image]

This is now dodged by gear, which is also used as size aesthetic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making sense of the question even though it was far from clear. I was struggling myself with how to formulate it. Does what I was hoping for!